# merge command in oracle causing out of space issues

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I have table1 with 3 million records in oracle db. I need to update one column for approx 2 million records in table1 using data from table2 and table3.

My data model for these 3 tables are

```
table1 has id, DOI
table2 has product_code, id
table3 has DOI and productcode
```

I am using merge command as update command is very time-consuming in this scenario.

```
merge into table1
using 
(select p.id, stg.doi from table2 p, table3 stg, table1 pc where stg.productcode = p.product_code and pc.product_id = p.id) st 
on (st.id = table1.product_id)
when matched then update set table1.doi = st.doi;
commit;
```

Since all these 3 tables has millions of records, temp table is always running out of space causing merge script to stop abruptly. DBA has assigned 64gb of space but still we are running out of temp space.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the "product_content" in your query? You are not mentioning it in the model.

Comment: @Hilarion i corrected the query now. Please check now.

Answer (score 2):

You could add `WHERE` clause:

```
merge into product_content
using (select p.id, stg.doi
       from table2 p
       JOIN table3 stg ON stg.productcode = p.product_code
       JOIN table1 pc  ON pc.product_id = p.id) st 
       -- modern explicit JOIN
on (st.id = product_content.product_id)
when matched then update set product_content.doi = st.doi
                  where product_content.doi != st.doi;  
                  -- assuming that doi is defined as NOT NULL
                  -- there is no need for update if nothing has changed
```

Comment: This is a good direction, although it may still not be enough, if there's a lot to actually update. In that case, doing the tasks in batches, and committing the changes after each batch, could be the solution.
**EDIT:** For easy batching, the update condition would have to go into the "using" query, and the query would have to have the row count limitation built in.

Comment: @Hilarion Yes, using batches is one approach. Another is some kind of column that indicate timestamp when row changed. Then during incremental load, OP could filter only rows that really changed instead of comparing entire table from source.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda - I tried your answer. Query is taking long time to complete. As suggested by you and Hilarion I will try doing this update in batches. Do you have any link how this bulk update can be done in batches?